# Installation of Jupyter Extensions - Automatic installation and enabling from setup.py

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, setuptools

I am trying to automate the installation and enabling of a Jupyter Extension, such that the user does not need to type commands:

```
jupyter nbextension install --user <my_fancy_module>
jupyter nbextension enable <the entry point> --user
```

As described in the [Jupyter Notebook documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Distributing%20Jupyter%20Extensions%20as%20Python%20Packages.html#Automatically-enabling-a-server-extension-and-nbextension), one could specify in `setup.py`:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="MyFancyModule",
    ...
    include_package_data=True,
    data_files=[
        # like `jupyter nbextension install --sys-prefix`
        ("share/jupyter/nbextensions/my_fancy_module", [
            "my_fancy_module/static/index.js",
        ]),
        # like `jupyter nbextension enable --sys-prefix`
        ("etc/jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.d", [
            "jupyter-config/nbconfig/notebook.d/my_fancy_module.json"
        ])
    ],
    ...
    zip_safe=False
)
```

However, when I try to run `pip install .` in the package directory, the installation finishes but `my_fancy_module` is not installed. Running:

```
jupyter nbextension install --user <my_fancy_module>
```

works well, since it correctly copies the whole `<my_fancy_module>` from my package directory inside `~/Library/Jupyter/nbextensions/`.

According to [Python documentation on Installing Additional Files](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files):

> `data_files` specifies a sequence of (directory, files) (...) Each (directory, files) pair in the sequence specifies the installation directory and the files to install there. (...) The directory **should be a relative path**. It is interpreted relative to the installation prefix (Python’s `sys.prefix` for system installations; `site.USER_BASE` for user installations).

My `site.USER_BASE` points at `~/.local`.

**My question is:**

How do I install and enable `my_fancy_package` from inside `setup.py` such that I end up with the same result as if I performed the two commands mentioned at the beginning? If this is about specifying `data_files` - what `directory` should I specify tere in order to successfully install and enable `my_fancy_module`?

I tried:

`"/Library/Jupyter/nbextensions/my_fancy_module"`, `"../Library/Jupyter/nbextensions/my_fancy_module"`, `"share/jupyter/nbextensions/my_fancy_module"`

but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `data_files` struggles to accept *absolute paths* as *destination*, but if you run `setup.py` with `--no-binary` flag, i.e. `pip install <my_package> --no-binary :all":` it works fine.

```
from os import path
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    data_files=[((path.expanduser('~') + '/Library/Jupyter/nbextensions/my_fancy_module', 
                  ['my_fancy_module/static/index.js']))]
    ...
)
```